# Con una tabla de movimientos y otra donde se registran votos, obtener todos los movimientos, tengan o no votos, en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero traer en una consulta todos los movimientos que tengan y no tengan votos en la tabla de votos. Al hacer el join, solo traen los que están en la tabla de votos: es decir, aquellos movimientos con votos registrados.

Esta consulta me trae la cantidad de votos correspondientes a cada movimiento, pero no trae todos los movimientos, o más bien los que no tienen votos.

```
SELECT m.NumeroLista,
    m.Movimiento,
    m.Siglas,
    SUM(rd.CantidadVotos) AS Votos 
FROM recuentodetalle rd
INNER JOIN recuento r ON r.IdRecuento=rd.FkRecuento 
INNER JOIN movimiento m ON m.idMovimiento=rd.FkMovimiento WHERE m.FK_Facultad =1 AND r.FkPadron =(SELECT idPadron FROM padron WHERE FK_idFacultad =1 AND Año =  YEAR(CURDATE()))  GROUP BY 1
```

[image: Texto]

Esta otra consulta me trae todos los movimientos que deseo pero la cantidad de votos no se corresponde:

```
SELECT m.NumeroLista,
    m.Movimiento,
    m.Siglas,
    COUNT(vv.TipoVoto) AS Votos 
FROM votosvalidos vv
 JOIN movimiento m 
 JOIN virtualcab vc WHERE m.FK_Facultad = 1 AND vc.Año =  YEAR(CURDATE())  GROUP BY 1
```

[image: Texto]

DER de la base de datos
[image: Texto]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tu primera consulta le hace falta un `LEFT JOIN`, en vez de `INNER JOIN`, y separar un poco las subconsultas para ir construyendo gradualmente lo que necesitas:

```
SELECT m.NumeroLista,
    m.Movimiento,
    m.Siglas,
    SUM(rd.CantidadVotos) AS Votos 
    FROM recuentodetalle rd
    JOIN recuento r ON r.IdRecuento=rd.FkRecuento 
    JOIN movimiento m ON m.idMovimiento=rd.FkMovimiento 
    WHERE m.FK_Facultad =1
    AND r.FkPadron =(
        SELECT idPadron 
            FROM padron 
            WHERE FK_idFacultad =1 
            AND Año =  YEAR(CURDATE())
    )
    GROUP BY 1;
```

En el caso de la segunda, además de evitar los productos cartesianos, `JOIN` sin `ON/USING`, debes hacer algo similar al primer caso, ir construyendo subconsultas que tengan el significado que esperas antes de combinarlas con otras tablas.

```
SELECT m.NumeroLista,
    m.Movimiento,
    m.Siglas,
    COUNT(vv.TipoVoto) AS Votos 
    FROM votosvalidos vv
    JOIN movimiento m 
    JOIN virtualcab vc
    WHERE m.FK_Facultad = 1
    AND vc.Año =  YEAR(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY 1;
```

Para poder ayudarte más, sería necesario que ampliaras tu pregunta añadiendo la estructura de tu base de datos con phpmyadmin y exportar; y nos mostraras los resultados que esperas para esos datos de ejemplo que nos facilitas.

A partir del diagrama que aportas (por favor, edita tu pregunta para que también lo contenga), ya te puedo proponer esta consulta en la que sí que aparecerán todos los movimientos con el número de votos obtenidos por cada uno:

[image: Diagrama de la base de datos]

```
SELECT *,IFNULL(n_votos,0) n_votos_finales
  FROM movimiento LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT FkMovimiento idMovimiento,
      SUM(CantidadVotos) n_votos
      FROM recuentodetalle
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(idMovimiento);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, como puedes ver enla primera imagen la cantidad de votos quese muestra es la correcta, sinembargo no se muestra el movimiento Tarta, que no posee votos en la tabla votosvalidos, en el caso de la segunada imagen si se muestra todos los movimientos pero la cnatidad de votos no es la correcta, loque busco es una consulta que me traiga tanto todos los mivimientos como en el segundo caso con su cantidad de votos correspondiente como en el primer caso, DER de la base de datos 
https://i.postimg.cc/1zGZ5Vc9/imagen.png

Comment: Me ha funcionado a la perfeccion, muchas gracias por la ayuda.